# Requisição GET não é respondida da forma correta pelo backend

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, maven

O projeto é um front-end em Angular 6, que se conecta a um back-end em Java para comunicação com um BD SQL Server.

O servidor que recebe o arquivo `.war`, contendo tando o back quanto o front, é o Tomcat 8.5.32.

A estrutura para execução do login segue quatro arquivos:

1. A classe AuthController, que oficializa o login em si.

   ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping(value = "/api")
   public class AuthController {

   public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthController.class);

   @CrossOrigin
   @RequestMapping("/auth")
   public Principal user(Principal principal) {
       logger.info("usuário logado " + principal);
       return principal;
     }
   }
   ```
2. A interface LoginRepository, para fazer queries no BD

   ```
   @Transactional
   public interface LoginRepository  extends JpaRepository<Login, Long>{
       Login findOneByUsername(String username);
   }
   ```
3. A classe-*service* UserService, que efetua queries no BD

   ```
   @Service
   public class UserService {
     @Autowired
     LoginRepository userRepository;

     public Login save(Login user) {
        return userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
     }

     public Login update(Login user) {
        return userRepository.save(user);
     }

     public Login find(String userName) {
        return userRepository.findOneByUsername(userName);
     }

     public Login find(Long id) {
        return userRepository.findOne(id);
     }

   }
   ```
4. E uma segunda classe-*service* UserDetailsServiceImpl

   ```
   @Service
   public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

   @Autowired
   UserService userService;

   @Override
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
       Login user = userService.find(username);
       return user;
     }

   }
   ```

Ao mandar uma requisição GET para o endpoint `/api/auth` em ambiente de desenvolvimento, com o servidor rodando no spring-boot, o login segue sem problemas, recebendo o objeto Principal e então logando no sistema.

Quando eu passo para o formato `war` com as devidas adaptações, testes que fiz mostram que as requisições para as outras tabelas seguem sem problema, com exceção do Login, que acessa o banco e faz a busca pela credencial, mas não retorna o objeto Principal, e sim um erro 404.

EDIT

Trechos do pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>br.com.tradeturismo.ServletInitialzer</start-class>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>ddMMyyyyHHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <angular.project.location>portal</angular.project.location>
    <angular.project.nodeinstallation>node_installation</angular.project.nodeinstallation>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${angular.project.location}</workingDirectory>
                <installDirectory>${angular.project.nodeinstallation}</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v10.6.0</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.1.0</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>npm build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <overwrite>false</overwrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/${angular.project.location}/dist</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Olá! O que retorna, então? Um erro?

Comment: Se não me engano, ele retorna ou um 404 ou um 401

Comment: @Dherik editei a pergunta com a resposta do back-end

Comment: Como deu um "Not Found Exception", você tem o trecho do log do Tomcat pra ficar mais fácil identificar o que não esta sendo encontrado?

Comment: @ayowoleagbedejobi não foi uma exception do java, e sim um erro HTTP 404

Comment: da uma lida nesse tutorial, acho que seu problema esta em conflito de portas que está utilizando e como declarar: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-angular-example

Comment: @UmProgramador hoje mais cedo em minhas pesquisas acabei encontrando justamente esse tutorial. Estou tentando adaptá-lo para o meu caso neste momento hehe

Comment: @mutlei, quais adaptações foram feitas para fazer o deploy do WAR?

Comment: Alterações no pom.xml. indicando a classe inicial do projeto, além de configurações para fazer a integração. Coloquei os plugins [da resposta desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45915379/how-to-setup-angular-4-inside-a-maven-based-java-war-project/45943326#45943326).

Comment: Adicionei uns detalhes do pom.xml na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente consegui desvendar o mistério.

Tive que alterar o valor da anotação `@RequestMapping` para `<nome-do-projeto>-<versão>`.

Por exemplo, se o seu projeto chama "eneias" e a versão dele é "1.0.0", a anotação deveria ficar assim:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eneias-1.0.0")
```

Isso apenas para a primeira anotação, que fica junto da declaração de classe. A segunda fica inalterada.

Answer (score -1):

Você está considerando o contexto da aplicação para realizar a chamada? por padrão é o nome do seu arquivo [nome].war

Teria que ser algo assim: http://localhost:8080/[nome]/api/auth

Comment: Sim, eu estou. O erro continua da mesma forma.